# Why the Higgs field has lower energy at non-zero value?

Tags: higgs

If I understood correctly, the Higgs field is responsible for giving elementary particles mass. And by Einstein's equation, the mass is equivalent to energy.

Wouldn't higher mass contribute to an overall higher energy?

I know that the Higgs field is responsible for giving mass only to elementary particles, and this is a tiny fraction of the observed mass.

However, if the Higgs field would be zero then wouldn't the overall mass (and thus energy be lower)?

Comment: This is the potential energy coming form the $V(\phi)$ term.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "the overall mass": the mass of what? In your very first question, "higher mass" refers to electrons, quarks, etc, or?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis I guess I am referring to overall mass of the universe or the average density may be a better term.

Comment: A cosmology question then. Are you aware that the Higgs field contribute to the "vacuum energy" regardless of the mass of particles? I mean, energy density is what matters in cosmology…